# how to create a postrgres query selecting a column instead of another if former exists

Tags: postgresql, information-schema

I need to create a query (in php but this does not really matters) for postgresql (9.1+) like this

```
select (<t1.column1 -if exists- or t2.column2>)::timestamp from t1 join t2 on <join field>
```

i was writing something along the lines of:

```
SELECT bytes_in, 
       coalesce((select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'table2' and column_name = 'override_tetime'), test_endtime)::timestamp as tetime
  FROM table2 t
  JOIN table1 tr ON (tr.id=t.tres_id)
 WHERE tetime BETWEEN '2016-06-01' AND '2017-01-01'
```

but the problem is that the retrieved field is a string and cannot be coalesced with the field `test_endtime` that is type *timestamp with time zone*

P.S. i'll explain a bit better what i need, the query could be between different tables: `table1` (in the example above) that will always include a `test_endtime` column and various other tables `table2...tableN` where may, or may not, be a `override_tetime` column; if the joined table has that column then the resulting rowset should use the timestamp from the `override_tetime` column.

Hope this is a bit more understandable now.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Are you sure you really want to check that a *column exists* or do you really want to check if the *value of a column* exists (which could probably be translated as `IS NOT NULL`) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this with a single statement in SQL.

You'd have to specify the name of `t1.column1` somewhere in the query (as identifier, not as string constant), and that will trigger a parse error if `t1` doesn't have a column named `column1`.

You'll have to check for column existence in a first query (probably querying the `information_schema` like you did) and then issue a second query that depends on the result of the first one.

If you don't want that logic in your application code, it would be easy to write a PostgreSQL function that does it for you.